# Change resolution/samples via python when executing it via console

Tags: python, command-line

I can't change Cycles's render samples via python when executing it via console,
I'm using this script and nothing changes at all:

script.py:

```
import bpy

resolution_x = 1023
resolution_y = 1025
samples = 32
format = 'JPEG'
JPEGQuality = 90

bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = resolution_x
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = resolution_y
bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = samples
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = format
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.quality = JPEGQuality
```

On the cmd:

`blender -b -P script.py file.blend -noaudio -E CYCLES -o outputrender -f 0 -F JPEG -- --cycles-device OPTIX`

Then the console says its rendering 0/196 samples, and its using about 3gb memory so its 4096x4096, both of those values are the default on the file.blend...

Comment: Argument order matters to blender and you need to put the `-P script.py` after all of the arguments meant for the render engine, except the `--cycles-device`

Comment: I attempted that without any different outcome